# Java upload file ftp server

Tags: java, file, upload, ftp

I am trying to make a function in Java :

```
public static void upload_files(String us, String pw, String ip, String f){
 try
 {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.connect(ip);
    client.login(us,pw);
    client.upload(f);
 } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

I added apache libraries, but sadly I got an error on "upload" line
I suppose I do not use correctly the method upload, but I don't know how to.

When I compile it with Netbeans, it is noticing me that there is an error line "client.upload(f);"

The error given in output is "*java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.upload*"

Thank you all in advance.
nb : "f" is the direct path to my file

---

EDIT :

The problem is "quite" solved since now I upload some files on my ftp server BUT sadly they are all empty, as noticed on below.

Comment: It'd be easier knowing the kind of error you're getting...

Comment: @ Adam : I simply can't run my program on netbeans because of this "client.upload(f)" line ...
"Cannot find symbol" according to the software.

Comment: Just copy paste the stacktrace here.

Comment: Cannot run or cannot compile?

Comment: Here is the error : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.upload"

Comment: When I look at the [Javadoc for Apache FtpClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html), I don't see an `upload` method.

Comment: @ Bhesh Gurung and Adam Zalcman : I added some details on below.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to remove the question. This makes the question completely useless for future visitors.

Comment: I see but this definitely needed to be updated :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache FTPClient does not have an `upload` method.

What it does have, is a method called [storeFile](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29)  .

It takes as it's parameters the name the file should have on the server, and an `InputStream`. The InputStream reads from your local file, so you need:

```
 InputStream is = new FileInputStream( f );
 client.storeFile( some_name, is );
```

Comment: now I got the same error with "storeFile", ie "cannot find symbol" thanks to netbeans.

And when I run it, this error appear: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: storeFile".

Comment: I don't think the error comes from netbeans. 

Here is the error after the compilation : "
error: cannot find symbol
        storeFile("test1", is );
  symbol:   method storeFile(String,InputStream)
  location: class main
1 error"

Comment: I see. Indeed, now some file is uploaded. Sadly the file is totally empty, but my main point was resolved. No I am wondering why my txt file is not uploaded. But I will have some "test1.txt" uploaded on my ftp server.

Comment: Should I open a new topic for such a question ? Or may we continue here ? Because the file which is uploaded is completely empty (0 B).

Comment: You may have to call `flush` or `close` on the InputStream. The API documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). It may appear a bit intimidating if you're new to Java, but it's quite clear when you get used to it.

Comment: I'm logging off now. I think you can find some answers by looking for code examples for FTPClient on the net, and in the FTPClient documentation. If that fails - "I get 0 bytes uploaded with FTPClient.storeFile" is, IMO, sufficiently different from your original question that you can post a new question. Good luck!

Comment: I can imagine that it's clear when you're used to it, but as you noticed well, this is not my case, and I am a bit sorry about it.
|||| After having checked I tried this code : 
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        client.storeFile("test1.txt", is );
        is.close();

But sadly it didn't worked. Nothing was sent to the server now :/

Comment: I just saw your answer about loggin off. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: In case you want to see it, here is the question you confirmed me to ask : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873353/empty-file-after-upload-with-java-on-my-ftp-server

Comment: You're welcome. I've deleted some of my comments to leave this page a bit cleaner.